# Scraping the right item

Tags: xpath, screen-scraping

I need to do this:

1. Sysyem ( web page ) ask a smartphone model to an user
2. User specify it in a form
3. System query some external page and with xpath extract what needed
4. System returns the cheapest item found ( if any ) with some xpath query on the external page, showing image, price, name, and giving the link to the original page

Now the problem is: if i order the results for descending price and i take the first, it's not the cheapest ( and sometime is not even the model i was looking for ), and if i take the last maybe will be not a smartphone, but a gadget like flip cover or other stuff.
I tought to use the xpath contains() to check if the name given at beginning by the user is present in the xpath query return value, but i found contains() is case sensitive, and is not so easy to make it case insensitive.
[Here](http://www.glistockisti.it/catalogsearch/result/?cat=15&dir=desc&disponibile=1067&order=price&q=note%204) you can find an example of the issues described above: i query for "note 4", order by price, and both first and last can't be taken.

Actually i use php to load and make query on desired page, and i can easilly extract all i need ( for example first, last or just another random block of items from the required page ) but i need some method to take exactly the cheapest and right model the user is looking for from all that noisy results.

Some other ideas?

Comment: Do you have some code to share or at least a business model ;)

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean with busyness model? more then code, i'm asking for ideas ... i edited my question, i hope to be more clear. thank you for your help :)

Comment: Unrelated, but here you have a hassle-free approach: http://fsockopen.com/php-programming/your-final-stop-for-php-xpath-case-insensitive